# Redux minimal state despite asynchronous calculations?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, redux, state

In my state tree, I have data `B` that is derived from state `A`.

`B` could be a picture, 3d geometry, music track, etc., and it is calculated *solely* based on parameters `A` already in the state tree.
But the key is that `B` is calculated asynchronously from `A`.

`B` changes whenever `A` changes. `B` may or may not be serializable.

The recommendation is to keep redux state minimal, and I was trying to use selectors to achieve this and remove `B` from state. However, since `B` is calculated asynchronously, it looks like I can't use selectors or memoized selectors like `reselect`. Is there any solution to this that allows state to stay minimal and not contain `B`?

Comment: do you need `B` to be stored? How do the components managing `A` look like?

Comment: Imagine A being just a couple params, e.g. numbers. The component could be a slider, check box, whatever appropriate to represent `A`.

Answer (score -1):

How many reducers do you have for your redux store? Are you using combinereducers() to manage multiple reducers? if so A and B could both be separate reducer with its own initial state and from your React Component to have it's own local state and dispatch asynchronous action-creator from corresponding lifecycle event method to update props

If those props that you pass down to B from A is only derived from its parent component doesn't need to be stored on initialstate from reducers, you can use [propTypes & defaultProps](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html). It allows you to assign prop types of props name for your component without having to put them in reducers.

for example here is source code of react bootstrap
you will see how that setup default props that needs to be pass to its component. when component has its own proptype and defaultprop set up you won't need to pass those props from redux store. You can generate prop values dynamically from your component A and pass them to B.

```
import classNames from 'classnames';
import React from 'react';
import elementType from 'react-prop-types/lib/elementType';

import { bsClass, prefix, splitBsProps } from './utils/bootstrapUtils';

const propTypes = {
  /**
   * Turn any fixed-width grid layout into a full-width layout by this property.
   *
   * Adds `container-fluid` class.
   */
  fluid: React.PropTypes.bool,
  /**
   * You can use a custom element for this component
   */
  componentClass: elementType,
};

const defaultProps = {
  componentClass: 'div',
  fluid: false,
};

class Grid extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { fluid, componentClass: Component, className, ...props } =
      this.props;
    const [bsProps, elementProps] = splitBsProps(props);

    const classes = prefix(bsProps, fluid && 'fluid');

    return (
      <Component
        {...elementProps}
        className={classNames(className, classes)}
      />
    );
  }
}

Grid.propTypes = propTypes;
Grid.defaultProps = defaultProps;

export default bsClass('container', Grid);
```

Comment: Of course, the case of both `A` and `B` in redux state is straightforward. There's even no need for component local state in that case, redux can handle it all. However, I'm asking about removing `B` from state because it's an object purely derived from `A`.

Comment: @bebbi I edited my answer about proptypes. did it help you?

Comment: No @Milo, it's not helpful. `propTypes` has nothing to do with the question, it's for prop validation. I'd recommend a good react-redux intro like Dan Abramovs "React Applications with Idiomatic Redux" on egghead.

Comment: @bebbi sorry to hear that. But proptype can also work on case when you don't have that particular prop pass down from parent component or when you don't want to have that prop from redux store as well. If you look into react bootstrap source code, those components has uses proptype to have its own props setup within itself, so even if you didn't pass certain props to bootstrap component that component still have default props that is created by using proptype. https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/master/src/Grid.js